# Get out of a foreach

Tags: java, php, foreach, break

My C++ teacher once told me that if I have to use a break to get out of a loop I didn't think enough about the loop condition.

So did she (very good teacher btw) just fail to mention that foreach loops are an exception to this rule (which I have generally found to be true) or is there indeed a way to get out of a foreach loop without using a break?

I am asking in general, but most interesting for me would be for Java or PHP.

Edit:
In case I haven't made this clear, I am wondering if there is a way to get out of a foreach-loop without using a break. Not sure what this whole commotion is about, what's wrong with that question?

Comment: Have you tried to implement and see what it actually does?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question ... yes, I have implemented foreach-loops ... ?

Comment: I don't agree with your teacher. Perhaps in the academic world of clearly defined exercises and problems she has a point. But in the real world of unpredictable users and massive data sets, breaking out of the loop when you know there's no point continuing is often the cleanest solution you have.

Comment: Are you looking for something that breaks out of a loop, but isn't called 'break'? Just to live by the mantra of a former teacher? PHP does have a `goto` statement that will do that. I'd personally stick with the `break` !

Comment: She ment that if you have a condition in your loop, that, if met, triggers a break you can combine this condition with your loop condition and therefor don't have to use the break.

Comment: I am looking for a way to exit a loop cleanly, like "Don't run if you don't have to" not "Break out when criteria x is met"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` loops don't have any exit condition except for the implicit "when there are no more items to iterate over", so it is not possible to break out of them early while avoiding `break` without using some sort of a terrible hack (e.g. throwing exception, modifying the iterated collection, setting a boolean flag `dontContinue` and checking it in each iteration, etc.).

For ordinary loops, there indeed always is an obvious way to avoid using `break` (stop the current iteration using `continue` or `if`, and put the early exit condition into loop's condition), however whether such approach leads to a more readable code than using `break` is disputable.

---

In some cases, the reason for you to want to break out of a loop early is because you finished whatever task needed to be done, or found the needed item. In such cases, consider putting the particular functionality into a separate method and using `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: Kinda what I already thought, since it completely makes sense. Was basically just looking for confirmation. Thanks